# How to update Kubernetes API version in deployment script or using --runtime-config

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I need to be able to use the `batch/v2alpha1` and `apps/v1alpha1` on k8s. Currently, I'm running a cluster with `1.5.0-beta.1` installed. I would prefer to do this in the deployment script, but all I can find are the fields

```
"apiVersionDefault": "2016-03-30",
"apiVersionStorage": "2015-06-15",
```

And nowhere can I find anything about what dates to use to update those. There are also some instructions in the kubernetes docs which explain how to use the `--runtime-config` flag on the kubes-apiserver.. so follow those, I ssh'd into master, found the kube-apiserver manifest file and edited it to look like such:

`apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Pod"
metadata:
  name: "kube-apiserver"
  namespace: "kube-system"
  labels:
    tier: control-plane
    component: kube-apiserver
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: "kube-apiserver"
      image: "gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v1.5.0-beta.1"
      command:
        - "/hyperkube"
        - "apiserver"
        - "--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota"
        - "--address=0.0.0.0"
        - "--allow-privileged"
        - "--insecure-port=8080"
        - "--secure-port=443"
        - "--cloud-provider=azure"
        - "--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/azure.json"
        - "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/16"
        - "--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001"
        - "--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.crt"
        - "--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
        - "--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt"
        - "--service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
        - "--v=4"
        - "--runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1,apps/v1alpha1"
      volumeMounts:
        - name: "etc-kubernetes"
          mountPath: "/etc/kubernetes"
        - name: "var-lib-kubelet"
          mountPath: "/var/lib/kubelet"
  volumes:
    - name: "etc-kubernetes"
      hostPath:
        path: "/etc/kubernetes"
    - name: "var-lib-kubelet"
      hostPath:
        path: "/var/lib/kubelet"`

That pretty much nuked my cluster.. so I'm at a complete loss now. I'm going to have to rebuild the cluster, so I'd prefer to add this in the deployment template, but really any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I opened a related issue https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/issues/178

Comment: I didn't. From what I could tell, because k8s on ACS is using hyperkube (i.e services running inside docker containers), updating anything is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

ACS-Engine clusters allow the ability to specify most any options you desire to override - see [this document for the cluster definitions](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/clusterdefinition.md). I don't think a post-deployment script exists because there are no common options you want to change with the apicontroller and other k8s components after a deployment other than K8s version upgrades.  For this purpose there are scripts included in ACS-Engine and other options for various cloud providers and flavors of kubernetes (i.e. Tectonic has a mechanism for auto-upgrades).

To manually override the values after the deployment of an ACS-Engine deployed K8s cluster, you can manually update the manifests here:

```
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
```

And also update the values in the kubelet here (i.e. to update the version of kubernetes): `/etc/default/kubelet`

Of course you'll want to `kubectl drain` your nodes before making these changes, reboot the node, and once the node comes back online and is running properly `kubectl uncordon` the node.

Hard to say why your cluster was nuked without knowing more information.  In general, I'd say it is probably best if you are making lots of changes to apiversions and configurations you probably want a new cluster.